# Double click to return to home page

Tags: double-click

Is there a jquery plugin for double clicking anywhere in a nuetral area to return to the home page?  Double click for a home page link?

Many thanks.

Comment: Add an event listener (double click) and bind that to a redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the double click event. Without seeing markup, not sure how you would make a selector for neutral area.

```
$("NEUTRAL AREA").bind("dblclick", function(){
    window.location.replace("http://yourdomain.com");
});
```